# Confused by root vs self.root and the use of __init__. Also confused with definitions and classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-3.6

first:

```
from tkinter import *


self.root = Tk()
self.root.configure(bg="red", padx=10, pady=10)
self.root.title("WELCOME- PLEASE LOGIN)")

name = Label(self.root, text="Name:", bg="magenta")
password = Label(self.root, text="Password", bg="magenta")
nameentry = Entry(self.root)
passwordentry = Entry(self.root)

name.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
nameentry.grid(row=0, column=1)
passwordentry.grid(row=1, column=1)

mainloop()
```

error on this code ( Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/pythonfolder/frametest.py", line 4, in 
    self.root = Tk()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined)

A window opens but is blank.

Next:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="red", padx=10, pady=10)
root.title("WELCOME- PLEASE LOGIN)")

name = Label(root, text="Name:", bg="magenta")
password = Label(root, text="Password", bg="magenta")
nameentry = Entry(root)
passwordentry = Entry(root)

name.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
nameentry.grid(row=0, column=1)
passwordentry.grid(row=1, column=1)

mainloop()
```

This works fine.

Why is using self.root causing an error vs just root?

Also:

```
from tkinter import *


def __init__(self, Event= None):

    root = Tk()
    root.configure(bg="red", padx=10, pady=10)
    root.title("WELCOME- PLEASE LOGIN)")

    name = Label(root, text="Name:", bg="magenta")
    password = Label(root, text="Password", bg="magenta")
    nameentry = Entry(root)
    passwordentry = Entry(root)

    name.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
    password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
    nameentry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    passwordentry.grid(row=1, column=1)

mainloop()
```

Causes this error using **init**:
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
Using self.root in place of root causes the same error. Removing event= None also causes this error.

Basically, I am confused on self.root vs root, definitions and their errors, and classes.

Comment: What did you expect `self` to be? `self` like any other variable, must be first defined. And for the last one, you shouldn't overwrite the default `__init__` of the file. I recommend reading a tutorial.

Comment: Well it worked before such as in this code

'code'
        from tkinter import *

        class Application(object):
        
            def __init__(self, event=None):
            
                self.root = Tk()
                self.root.configure(bg="darkorchid1", padx=10, pady=10)
                self.root.title("WELCOME TO MY PROGRAM)")
            
                self.username = "Bob"

'code'
sorry for the formatting, not sure how to show code in comments - i'm new. If you could explain how to format the code like in the main post I will do so, and would appreciate it.

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  \[link](http://example.com) \_italic_ \**bold** \`code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: this is what it said inside help

Comment: (Had the ` as' lol) Well it worked before such as in this code  `from tkinter import *`
`class Application(object): def __init__(self, event=None):`
`self.root = Tk() self.root.configure(bg="darkorchid1", padx=10, pady=10)`
`self.root.title("WELCOME TO MY PROGRAM)") self.username = "Bob"` Still not sure how to get the lines formatted right @abccd

Comment: Well that's the best what anyone can do in comments, if you wanted to paste blocked codes, edit your original question as a EDIT. This is not what commenting is for

Comment: you see, everything before that you said it worked was inside a class, but in your questions last example, `def __init__` was in the global scope-not inside a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is a class level identifier. When you type `self.root = Tk()` it means  in this class it will create a class level variable `root` and initialize it with `Tk()` object and whenever you want to access this variable in the class you will call it with `self.root` like `self.root.title()`

A little demo:

```
class demo(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def change_a(self, new_a):
        self.a = new_a

 obj1 = demo(10) # will call the init fn of class and create a class level variable a = 10
 print(obj1.a) # will print 10 which is stored in class level variable for obj1

obj1.change_a(20) # will call the fn and change the class level variable a = 20
print(obj1.a) # will print 20 becuase class level variable a was changed
```

It is not as simple as it look's like so but I think now you have a little idea

Comment: I think I understand but how is obj1 called by demo and not __init__?
I would think you would need type obj1 = __init__(10)?

Comment: there are some default functions with special purposes like `__init__()` will be called whenever a new class object will be defined `__str__()` will be called when some will do `print(obj1)` and many more similar. so auto calling functions are here some special purposes.

Comment: @gmonz `__init__` is what is called a class "constructor" ... it gets called when you create an "instance" of a class.  

`obj1 = demo(10)` is where he is creating an "instance" of the class demo.   The 10 is an argument that gets passed to the "constructor" `__init__` when it gets created.

the "self" is the identifier used thought the code of class that means "this instance" of the class...